# How will the Toast be displayed, based on Activity/Fragment height and width (or) Device Screen width and height?

Tags: android, android-toast

I use a fragment in a dialog box and I have buttons in the fragment.

When I click on the button, toast should display, but it doesn't work as desired.

How will the toast be displayed, based on Activity/Fragment height and width (or) Device screen height and width?

Comment: Please add your code!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the android toast will display at the bottom.
but we can change the position of the toast as desired for the client's requirement for example

if you want to display the toast in the center of the screen means then use the following code

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"toast display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Toast` displayed based on the whole activity.

Docs:

> A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup.
>   It only fills the amount of space required for the message and the
>   current activity remains visible and interactive. Toasts automatically
>   disappear after a timeout.

You can use a Toast within a dialog fragment as following:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also you can create your own custom toast [Make a custom toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts#CustomToastView) as following steps:

1.Create your custom layout(e.g. name it `custom_toast.xml`) note that this step is optional.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
              >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/droid"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

2.Create your custom Toast object and set the optional custom layout for that:

```
// Inflate the custom layout:
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

// Fill the custom layout with your own data
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

// Create the toast and set the custom layout to it
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Thank you sir for php version answer edit , I truly appreciate your efforts from bottom of my heart